# Extracting Dynamic String from a String

Tags: apex, class

In the below Email body, I need to grab the External Account Id (4891 in the below example), however, that text can be between 4 and 8 characters long.

Once I have the ID I'll find a matching account with the same External ID and stamp that Account on the Case I'm creating.

```
External Account Id: 4891
---------------------------------------
ContactName: John
ContactPhoneNumber: (212) 555-3554
WebsiteUrl: http://google
WorkFlow: 26612707
```

Thoughts? Everything I've found so far tells me to specify the character count but that doesn't work for me here.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: you can also look for a text between "External Account Id:" and next end of the line. Whatever is inside those, should be an account id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the flow you should do:

- Add a Util method getExternalIdFromEmail with return type String that
  returns the external id and pass the email body content as the
  argument
- Inside the method, Split the email body content with '\n' (newline character) to
  separate the content into each line.
- Identify the message line that contains 'External Account Id'
- Split this line using ':' as the separator
- You will get two Strings from the above split, one containing the text 'External Account Id' and the other containing the external id
- Trim the leading and trailing spaces and return the value

```
private static String getExternalIdFromEmail(String emailContent){

    if(String.isEmpty(emailContent)) return null;

    String externalIdLine;
    String externalId;
    for(String msgBodyLine : emailContent.split('\n')) {
        if(!String.isEmpty(msgBodyLine) && msgBodyLine.containsIgnoreCase('External Account Id')) {
            externalIdLine = msgBodyLine;
            break;
        } 
    }
    if(externalIdLine != null) {
        externalId = externalIdLine.split(':')[1].trim();       
    }
    return externalId;    
}
```

Comment: This works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
String externalId = myEmailBody
  .substringBetween('External Account Id:','-----')
  .normalizeSpace();
```

See [String class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm?search_text=string%20class)